# Is there a way to write a file to an FTP Server that uses SSL using R?

Tags: r, ssl, rcurl, ftps, quickbase

I have an R script that pulls data down from QuickBase in a .csv format using RCurl. Currently, when using the write.table function I just direct it to a local folder. I am wanting to write directly to an FTP Site that I believe is using SSL. I have a username and password and can connect using clients such as cyberduck after choosing the type of connection "FTP - SSL (Explict AUTH Over TLS)".

I have tried just using the ftpUpload function but it refuses to let me to make the connection.

Any help or advice on where to look next is appreciated.

Comment: Your test with cyberduck is from the same machine as the one with RCurl ?

Comment: are you able to curl using `--ftp-ssl` option from the command line? some same command can be found here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html when you search for ftp

Answer (score 0):

## High Level

The best way I am aware of to get this done (in R) is to wrap a call to a system function. I personally use [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html), which has good handling for:

- FTPS
- Multiple files in/out
- Regex and wildcard file naming

This does have the downside of being hardware specific; it's not all nicely contained in R. That said, it *can* potentially save you a lot of time by leveraging tools which are good at what they do.

---

## Sample Wrapper

A wrapper for LFTP could look like the function below -- this is a variant of what I use in production; I stripped out the logging functions which depend on a broader package. At the core, this is what moves files for me.

```
#' lftp wrapper to get/put file(s) from ftp-like sites
#'
#' @param process list, pipeable etl objects
#' @param configuration vector (text), list of
#' arguments to supply after call to lftp
#' @param skip boolean, whether to skip this step (testing)
#'
#' @details wrapper around lftp command line tool
#'
#' @export
#'
ftp <- function(configuration, skip = FALSE) {
    if (!skip) {
        system2("lftp",
            args = configuration)
    }
}
```

### Configuration

The biggest part of the wrapper is the `configuration` vector. The configuration vector lets you pass an arbitrary set of parameters to `lftp`, including the ones you'll need to get the job done.

A sample configuration vector could look like:

```
c(
    'your.ftp-server.com',
    paste("-e", '"put '/path/to/file.csv' -o '/destination/'; exit;"'
)
```

Noting that you need to be careful about quoting (or you can incorporate [shQuote()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/shQuote.html), but that's a different project).

## Putting It Together

To answer your specific question, you could use this in R to:

- Get the data you're using from Quick Base using `rCurl`
- Write it to a file somewhere on your hardware
- Use ftp() to leverage `lftp` to send the file to its destination